# Can't get shortcodes from post to display in theme on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom theme for wordpress and am trying to add a carousel to the front page, I was able to add the carousel in and it's all working when I hard code the images in. What I am trying to do now is make the images module using shortcodes in the page content.

What I'm now trying to do is set the image src from the page content in the admin dashboard like so:

```
<div id="img-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#img-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#img-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>

        <?php if( shortcode_exists( 'carousel-img3' ) && !empty( do_shortcode( '[carousel-img3]' ) ) ) { ?>
        <li data-target="#img-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <?php } ?>

    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1903x647" alt="item0">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1903x647" alt="item1">
        </div>

        <?php if( shortcode_exists( 'carousel-img3' ) && !empty( do_shortcode( '[carousel-img3]' ) ) ) { ?>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="<?php echo do_shortcode( '[carousel-img3]' ); ?>" alt="item2">
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

My shortcode function is as follows:

```
function carousel_img3_func( $params = null, $content ) {
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'carousel-img3', 'carousel_img3_func' );
```

My page looks like this in wordpress admin

```
[carousel-img3]http://placehold.it/1903x647[/carousel-img3]
```

When I view the page nothing is shown, I then change the `do_shortcode()` to the following

```
do_shortcode( '[carousel-img3]http://placehold.it/1903x647[/carousel-img3]' )
```

and this adds the image in and shows in the carousel. Is there anyway that I can get it to pull the shortcode information directly from page with the ability of adding more shortcodes in the future, to add more images. e.g.

```
[carousel-img3]http://placehold.it/1903x647[/carousel-img3]
[carousel-img4]http://placehold.it/1903x647[/carousel-img4]
```

Comment: This *may* have to do with the hyphens in your shortcode name. Try changing `carousel-img3` to `carousel_img3` everywhere

Comment: @rnevius I thought that too I have tried with hyphens underscores and neither work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using shortcodes is not the correct way to edit the theme instead a theme options page should be used. I have done this using the Wordpress codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change the structure to:

```
//[carousel images="foo.jpg,bar.jpg"]
function carousel_func( $atts ) {
    $ouptput = "";
    $images = explode(",",$atts['images'];
    foreach($images as $image){
        $output .= "<div class='item'><img src='" . $image . "' /></div>";
    }
    return $output
}
add_shortcode( 'carousel', 'carousel_func' );
```

Comment: I have tried this code it is doing the same as mine, if I hard code the image urls to the theme it shows but it doesn't pull from the post content

Comment: Could you post your html code after the code has run? Or a link?

Comment: Sorry no link the site is currently offline, however the html output shows none of the item divs looks like `<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"></div>` how ever if I add `<?php echo do_shortcode( '[carousel images="foo.jpg,bar.jpg"]' ); ?>` to the template file it does add images to the page but I don't want to hard code it into the template file.

Comment: I think you are confusing how shortcodes work. If you add a shortcode in your content editor in Wordpress, it will be replaced by the output of the shortcode function. So we need 3 things: 1) shortcode in your content editor 2) shortcode function 3) output of the content editor in your template file. You are missing 3). This could be either in the_content or inside a custom field.

Comment: thank you @Tom Broucke I will have to look at a different way of doing this.

Comment: No problem. I would use ACF for this. (repeater field). It is quite easy to implement: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/